# A Set $S$ is Closed iff $S = \mathrm{cl} \, S$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

First, suppose that $S$ is closed and let $x \in S$. Hence, $x \in \mathrm{cl} \, S$, so $S \subseteq \mathrm{cl} \, S$. Now suppose that $x \in \mathrm{cl} \, S$ such that $x \in S'$, where $S'$ denotes the set of accumulation point of $S$. Since $S$ is a closed set, $S' \subseteq S$, implying that $x \in S$. Therefore, $\mathrm{cl} \, S \subseteq S$. We conclude that $S = \mathrm{cl} \, S$ whenever $S$ is closed.

Assume now that $S = \mathrm{cl} \, S$. Since $\mathrm{cl} \, S$ is a closed set and $S = \mathrm{cl} \, S$, it follows that $S$ is also closed, as desired.

Any thoughts concerning this proof? Is the second paragraph of the proof O.K., or could it be more rigorous?

Comment: "Since $S$ is a closed set and ..." should be  "Since $cl\ S$ is a closed set and ..."

Comment: oh, yeah, that was a typo. thanks.